# After adding @addTagHelper to the _ViewImports.cshtml, the ASP.NET project doesn't run

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The web application was running fine until I added 
   `@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"` 
to the _ViewImports.cshtml. There are no build errors and the build runs successfully but I don't see anything in the browser. Also, it doesn't show any source code. And as soon as I remove the above code from the file, the application runs normally. I have also included the `"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"` in the dependencies. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the version of `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers`. All the other dependencies were of version "1.0.0-rc1-final" and `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers` was of version "6.0.0-beta8". Just added the same version to TagHelpers and problem solved.